# Why doesn't this radial-gradient complete the circle?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I'm trying to use a radial gradient to create a border within circle elements that are radio buttons. The basic CSS is shown below. I cannot figure out why the red gradient does not circle the entire circumference of the circles.

As the white color-stop approaches 100%, gaps appear in the red at the top, right, left, and bottom.

Why does this happen, and how would I fix it while still using a radial gradient?

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.radio1 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 75%, red 100%); }
.radio2 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 90%, red 100%); }
.radio3 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 95%, red 100%); }
.radio4 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 99%, red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
  <div class="radio radio1"></div>
  <div class="radio radio2"></div>
  <div class="radio radio3"></div>
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

Also on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvgcs80f/

Comment: If you didn't feel like messing with the gradients, a simpler alternative might be `box-shadow`.  Something like `box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px red;`. Of course, you asked *why* and *how* with a radial gradient, so this isn't really an answer - just an option :)

Comment: `background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 99%, red 100%);`will not cover a single pixel in a 20px square boxe, so it's even impossible mission to draw a gradient, at 75% to 100% the gradient has about 2.5 pixels to be drawn ... It does not work because your boxes are too small :( the second box has 2pixel to faint from red to white, third and fourth have no chance to draw your gradient

Comment: @TylerRoper If I do that, the white background goes away. Is there a way to keep both?

Comment: turn your box to 200px and to 300px and see that it woks fine, .. because there  will the minimum and enough room to draw the gradients :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your percentage will be converted to pixel relatively to the width/height of your element. In your case, your element is small thus `99%` and `100%` will most likely be converted to the same value or very close values and you will have subpixel rendring issue.

Instead you can rely on `calc()` where you can easily define the thickness as a pixel value independently of the element size.

You need to also adjust `background-origin` and make it `border-box` so that you draw the gradient considering the border area and you will have a perfect circle.

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.radio1 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 1px), red 100%); }
.radio2 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 2px), red 100%); }
.radio3 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 3px), red 100%); }
.radio4 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
  <div class="radio radio1"></div>
  <div class="radio radio2"></div>
  <div class="radio radio3"></div>
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

---

Here is an example with big values of border to better illustrate the issue related to `background-origin`

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

The background is drawn on the padding box then it's getting repeated over all the area (border box).

If you disable the repeat you will have this:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

Here is if we repeat only on the X axis

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

And here is what is happening when using 100% for both colors which is similar to your situation and you will better understand why you have coloration only on the corners.

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 100%, red 100%);
}

.one {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.two {
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.three {
  border-width: 5px;
}
.four {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio one"></div>
  <div class="radio two"></div>
  <div class="radio three"></div>
  <div class="radio four"></div>
</div>
```

---

And if we change the origin it's fine:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-origin:border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer that went above what I expected. Thank you!