# Why does a border that has opacity make a square inside a circle when I use radial-gradient(circle at)?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

When I have a circle in css with background: radial-gradient(circle at 75px 50px, #5cabff, #003) and add a border that has an opacity, it makes the circle look like it has a square inside it. Why is this happening and is there a solution for this to not happen?

```css
.style {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 27px solid #00000030;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 75px 50px, #5cabff, #003);
}
```

```html
<div class="style"></div>
```

I expected when adding the border with opacity to not have in the circle a square shape, but a 3d sphere with a border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the `background-origin` to make it `border-box` so that the gradient consider the border as its area too. By default `background-origin` is set to `padding-box` whereas `background-clip` is set to `border-box` making the background to repeat on the border creating the strange effect:

I also added the `27px` of the border to the center of the circle since now the border is considered in the calculation.

```css
.style {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 27px solid #00000030;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 102px 77px, #5cabff, #003) border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="style"></div>
```

Related to get more details about the background-origin issue: [Why doesn't this radial-gradient complete the circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56399252/8620333)